# Insert counter enemies killed

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a simple 2D play and would like to implement a counter for every enemy killed and keep it displayed on the display until the game is over.

How would I do this? I'm using Xcode 7.3.1

**My Enemies code is :**

```
func frecciaInCollisioneConNemico(freccia:SKSpriteNode, nemico:SKSpriteNode) {
    print("Freccia ha colpito un nemico")
    freccia.removeFromParent()
    nemico.removeFromParent()

    nemiciDistrutti += 1
    print("hai distrutto \(nemiciDistrutti) nemici")

    if (nemiciDistrutti >= 20) {
        let rivela = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        let gameOverScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, vinto: true)
        self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: rivela)
    }
}
```

Comment: what about your question from 2013?

Comment: I am not going to answer this, and I hope nobody does because this is a simple problem that you can solve without the help of the community.  Start a brand new Sprite Kit project, that will teach you how to display text onto the scene.  I am assuming nemiciDistrutti is your enemy kill counter, just put the 2 together and you have your answer.

Comment: Looks like you _did_ answer the question

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to answer this question by yourself as it is very easy.

Create your label

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    let enemiesKilledLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "HelveticaNeue")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        loadEnemiesKilledLabel()  
    }

    private func loadEnemiesKilledLabel() {
        enemiesKilledLabel.position = ...
        enemiesKilledLabel.text = "0"
        ...
        addChild(enemiesKilledLabel)
    }
}
```

Than in your death function you just update the text.

```
 ...
 nemiciDistrutti += 1

 enemiesKilledLabel.text = "\(nemiciDistrutti)" // update text
```

This is called string interpolation, you can read more about it here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

As a tip you should change your collision method to take in optionals. There could be a case where 1 collision calls multiple contacts because multiple body parts collided. Your code is not taking this into account and therefore you could crash if frecciaInCollisioneConNemico is called multiple times in fast succession.

Change it to this

```
func frecciaInCollisioneConNemico(freccia: SKSpriteNode?, nemico: SKSpriteNode?) {

    guard let freccia = freccia, nemico = nemico else { return }

    freccia.removeFromParent()
    nemico.removeFromParent()
    ...
}
```

Lastly I would recommend you try to write your code in english only.

Hope this helps

Comment: He doesn't. The scene change does not happen until the counter reaches 20. Furthermore in his description he says "...would like to implement a counter for every enemy killed and keep it displayed on the display until the game is over."

Comment: Hi, I'll try as soon as possible your "crashoverride777" explanation.
thank you so much response, next time I will write in English totally code.


As for the kind reply of "Knight0fDragon" only say that if I asked this question is because I could not find solutions on the internet, only a beginner, maybe you're an absolute genius, and no one is born learned.


Thanks again to those who helped me.

Comment: You are very welcome. If it works, which it will, please be so kind to mark my answer. Happy coding.